# How come my Django code doesn't rollback changes when there is an error?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

Below is my code. (It's run by Celery, but I don't think that's important.)
When an error occurs, the mongo record gets removed (yay!) but the .rollback() does not work, so mysql keeps the record instead of rolling it back. Why?

```
class Submitter(Task):
    @transaction.commit_manually
    def run(self, post, **kwargs):
        docDB = h.connect_mongo(collection="posts")

        post = cPickle.loads(post)
        if post.has_key("original_file"):
            try:
                post = docProcessor.process_images(post)
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
        post['processed'] = True

        #START INSERT -------
        try:
            mongo_id = docDB.insert(post)
            author = User.objects.get(id=post['author_id'])

            #Sync mysql content with mongo id
            c, created = Content.objects.get_or_create(mongo_id = str(mongo_id), author=author)
            c.save()

            #now update the content_id
            post['content_id'] = c.id
            post['_id'] = mongo_id
            updated = docDB.save(post)

            #finally, add a vote to the document.
            h.insert_vote(content_id = c.id, lat = post['loc_latlong'][0],
                     long = post['loc_latlong'][1],
                     ip = post['ip'], thevote = 1, theuser = author, mongo_con = docDB)

            transaction.commit()
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
            docDB.remove(post)
        #END INSERT --------

        return True
```

Comment: Can you tell us what error is occurring?

Comment: To test this code, I purposely introduced some wrong stuff.  Then, the exception hit.  It's supposed to rollback(), but mysql doesn't roll it back.  Mongo does remove the post though.  There's no error. It simply just goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not using the InnoDB table engine, which, unlike MyISAM, supports transactions.

Comment: How did you know which DB engine he's using?